# About positive zeros of a function

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

There is a rule called the 'Descartes' rule of signs' which gives a bound for the number of positive zeros of polynomials. Also, there are many extensions for this rule for exponential polynomial.

Are there some rules regarding the number of positive zeros for the sum or product of functions? For example, any inequality giving a relation between the number of positive zeros of sum/product of functions and the positive zeros of functions.

What I mean is: **Can we have an upper bound for $Z(f+g)$, where $Z$ denotes the number of positive zeros?** Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since your functions are defined in a field F like R, if there was nonzero a and b with a*b=0, you would get a*a^-1*b*b^-1=0=1. Therefore you get a*b=0 => a =0 or b=0. Then you have for any product of functions the same thing ie product(f_i(x)) = 0 means that theres a zero on a f_i

Comment: what about Sum?

Comment: since your functions are defined in a field you have f : x |--> 1 and -f (ie f: x|--> -1). They don't have any zero and f+(-f)=0 is total zero. So there's likely to be no rules

Comment: My example destroys at least any rule with the form f(zeros_of_the_subfunctions) >= zeros_of_the sum for finite number of zeros in the subfunction.